# How can I edit old template in WPF

Tags: wpf, vb.net, wpf-controls

I trying to create new custom control named PlaceHolderTextBox inherited from TextBox. So I added a TextBlock directly above the TextBox using Template :

```
<!-- PlaceHolderTextBox template -->

<ControlTemplate TargetType="TextBox">
    <Grid>
        <TextBlock x:Name=""holder"" />
        <ScrollViewer  x:Name=""PART_ContentHost"" Margin=""0"" />
    </Grid>
</ControlTemplate>
```

All are ok for now, the real TextBox will appear in the ScrollViewer automatically. Now I want to derive this class to create my AutocompleteTextBox control inherited from PlaceHolderTextBox, so I have to edit template again, but how can I add the base control PlaceHolderTextBox to the template like I did by ScrollViewer above? !!

```
<!-- AutocompleteTextBox template -->

<Grid>
    <PlaceHolderTextBox Name=""tbTextBox""/>

    <Popup x:Name=""pop""    
                           Visibility=""Visible""
                           StaysOpen=""False""    
                           Placement=""Bottom"">

        <ListBox x:Name=""lbSuggestions""       
                 Height=""135""    
                 />
    </Popup>
</Grid>
```

The problem in the PlaceHolderTextBox control shown in the template, it will be treated as new control (not bound to the inherited properties like Text) and not like the ScrollViewer in the first class.

I tried to use PART_XXX mechanism in the base class to solve this issue, but I failed to edit incoming template -like ScrollViewer did- before use :

```
Public Class PlaceHolderTextBox
Inherits TextBox

Public Overrides Sub OnApplyTemplate()

    Dim host = Me.GetTemplateChild("PART_PlaceHolderContentHost")
    If host IsNot Nothing AndAlso TypeOf host Is Grid Then
        Dim xaml = "<Grid>
                        <TextBlock x:Name=""holder"" />
                        <Grid x:Name=""PART_ContentHost"" Margin=""0"" />
                    </Grid>"
        Dim strReader = New StringReader(xaml)
        Dim xmlReader = Xml.XmlReader.Create(strReader)
        Dim grid As Grid = XamlReader.Load(xmlReader)
        CType(host, Grid).Children.Add(grid)
    End If

    MyBase.OnApplyTemplate()
End Sub
End Class
```

So I added new controls to the grid (PART_PlaceHolderContentHost) but ScrollViewer here will not work correctly because it added to the real grid (not template). So how can I edit incoming template to make ScrollViewer treated as TextBoxBase.